# PayPal Integration in iOS Apps

Tags: ios, swift, paypal, braintree

I've been developing my app for quite some time and I need to integrate PayPal. I tried Braintree but I found out it is not supported in my country. I've been searching and found same questions here but so far everything seems to be vague and not clear. So I tried and followed the steps from this link provided by PayPal https://developer.paypal.com/docs/accept-payments/express-checkout/ec-braintree-sdk/get-started/ but it still needs the merchant id, private and public key which can only be found in Braintree. Am I missing something from the resources around here?

Comment: Yes, Braintree is available in limited country. So you need to integrate PayPal in your app using webview.

Comment: Did you find any solution?

Answer (score 1):

Try and follow the steps below :

1. Download the iOS Mobile Payments Library SDK from Paypal(Make sure
   you include all MPL components inside your app)
2. Get your App ID and use the Paypal sandbox App ID
3. Specify your environment for testing
4. Include your values in the MPL call
5. Set your payment types
6. Make your payment calls (at this stage if everything is successful,
   the user is normally presented with the in-app Paypal login screen,
   and the user makes payment which happens inside your app)
7. On completed payment, the MPL returns control to your app

Comment: Answers that consist of just a link are discouraged by SO. Links can break. Answers should contain some indication of how the problem should be solved.